# Python virtualenv Windows

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I am working my virtualenv with my Ubuntu system. Is it possible to use this virtualenv in a Windows system without Python installation?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if what you want is use virtualenv in windows without using python, I don't think that's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, you need to install Python on Windows too and you will need to install the requirements again.

On your Ubuntu system create a requirements.txt file with the command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then create a virtualenv on Windows, copy the previous file and install all the requirements with the following command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```